# What does `LBUFFER%%(#m)[_a-zA-Z0-9]#` do in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I need help understanding what the following code in [this](http://zshwiki.org/home/examples/zleiab) documentation means.

```
LBUFFER=${LBUFFER%%(#m)[_a-zA-Z0-9]#}
LBUFFER+=${abbreviations[$MATCH]:-$MATCH}
```

I learned that `LBUFFER` contains the left from the cursor. However, there are 3 things that confuse me.

1. What is the `%%` doing? Is it escaping `%`?
2. What does `(#m)[_a-zA-Z0-9]#` do? Is it something like `m/[_a-zA-Z0-9]/` in Perl? If so, what is done to the matched string?
3. What is the `:-` part doing in the second line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `${a%%b}` removes the longest occurrence of `b` (which can be a regular expression), from `a`.
2. `[_a-zA-Z0-9]#` is a regular expression matching an alphanumeric character (as indicated by the stuff between `[]`) **zero or more times** (specified by the `#` glob operator)
3. `(#m)` populates the `$MATCH` variable after evaluating the previous regular expression.
4. The combination of 1, 2, and 3 means that the stretch of alphanumeric characters at the end of the `$LBUFFER` is deleted and stored in `$MATCH`.
5. `${a:-b}` makes `a` equal to `b` only if `a` is not defined.

If you want to learn more, take a look at the [expansion chapter](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html) of the zsh manual.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. One thing to make sure, the second `#` is just a character and doesn't have any syntactical meaning, right?

Comment: Never mind, I was wrong. The `#` is a glob operator that means zero or more times when it appears after a regular expression (it is the equivalent of `*` in Perl). I've updated my answer.